# What makes a Decimal datatype higher precision for decimal numbers than the datatype Double?

Tags: .net

Why can a decimal number always be accurately represented in a Decimal datatype whereas in a Double it cannot.

Does a Decimal datatype have more bits in the Mantissa?

Is a Decimal datatype normalised?

Comment: A decimal is stored with a "10 to the power of ..." exponent, whereas double and float are stored with a "2 to the power of ...". This means that double and float have trouble storing normal base 10 numbers accurately, whereas decimal doesn't, as long as it is within the range of precision.

Comment: For instance, storing 0.33 in double is problematic, but not in decimal, as it is simple stored as 33 * 10^-2.

Comment: I am pretty sure there are existing answers here on Stack Overflow that details the actual method this is done, so I'm not going to leave an answer, but until these duplicates are found, you can read more about decimal type [here](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Decimal#:~:text=How%20is%20a%20decimal%20stored,representing%20the%20sign%20and%20exponent.).

Comment: Lasse, many thanks for your response. I know that when decimal numbers are represented by a float/double, the fractional part of the decimal number is represented by the fractional part of the binary number (this is why inaccuracies can occur). However, having read what you have written and the article you have posted, the decimal datatype doesn’t use fractional binary to represent the fractional part of a decimal number. That explains to me why inaccuracies do not occur for decimal numbers represented by the Decimal datatype.

Comment: @nish91 - You're overthinking it. Both `decimal` and `double` are binary representations of a subset of the set of real numbers. Since real numbers are infinite and the number of bits used to represent `decimal` and `double` are finite then both representations have inaccuracies. There's no escaping that. `double` has been designed to represent a large scale of numbers (roughly up to 1.8 x 10 ^ 308), but it has holes in the representation of typical monetary values. `decimal` has been designed to be better at that, but it doesn't have the large range of values.

Comment: The "always" in the first sentence is quite wrong.  Decimal takes 16 bytes and can store 28 digits, Double takes 8 and stores 15, Single takes 4 and stores (almost) 7.  The more storage, the more digits.  Encoding the value in base10 avoids surprises with human numbers, 1 divided by 10 has no exact representation in base2, just like 1 divided by 3 (or 6, 7, 9, etc) has none in base10.